# How to get all images in the resources as list?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a WinForms project and added multiple images to the resources (project properties -> Resources). Now I have a Form1.cs, a UserControl1.cs with a .resx files, and using `Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()`, it contains 3 strings namely:

**1** TestApplication1.Properties.Resources.resources,
**2** TestApplication1.Form1.resources
**3** TestApplication1.UserControl1.resources

What I need to get now is obviously the files from #1 which contains the images I need to get. What I need to do is have a list that I can access these images through their indexes. I can access this files individually with no problem, but I have 72 images so I need them as a list. So my question is, how do I get these images in #1 as a list?

**EDIT:**
Is there no other way as to create a list and add all of my 72 images to it? Or is there some way that I can get all of these images from the resources as a list? Also, I don't want to resort to using `System.IO` as I will build this application as a Class Library.

Comment: How do you access a single image?

Comment: I mean using `Resources.Image1`, `Resources.Image2`, and so on, but I cannot do this for my 72 images so I'm asking for a way to have the images as a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each `.resx` file is compiled into a single "composite" embedded `*.resources` resource blob that is located in your assembly. I appreciate this is confusing as it means the term "resource" is overloaded to refer to both the `.resources` blob, but also the individual contents of each blob.

Use the `ResourceManager` class to retrieve named items from within a `.resources` file.

Note that if you're using the `.resx` designer in Visual Studio then you don't need to use `ResourceManager` directly, you simply use the generated `Resources` class, like so:

```
using MyProject.Properties;

...

this.label1.Text = Resources.SomeLabelText;
```

(Where `SomeLabelText` is the key name)

By default, the designer-generated `Resources` class will be under the `Properties` child namespace.

To enumerate resources you'll need to use `ResourceManager`, like so:

```
ResourceSet rsrcSet = MyProject.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet( CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, false, true );

foreach( DictionaryEntry entry in rsrcSet ) {
    String name = entry.Key;
    Object resource = entry.Value;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, compiler throws an error 'System.Resources.ResourceSet.Table' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: @EricJohnIgnacio I have revised my answer to use `ResourceSet`'s built-in `IEnumerable` implementation to get `DictionaryEntry` values.

Comment: `GetResourceSet` has 3 arguments and you didn't supply them in your code. I used `var resources = Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, false, true);` and resources returned null.

Comment: Nevermind, I used true in the second argument and it returned what I need thanks!

Answer (score 4):

To get all images in a `resx` file, you can use either of these options:

**ResourceManager.GetResourceSet**

Based on [Dai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34826151/3110834) you can use [`ResourceManager.GetResourceSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.getresourceset(v=vs.110).aspx) and then filter and shape the the result this way:

```
var images = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager
                       .GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true, true)
                       .Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
                       .Where(x => x.Value.GetType() == typeof(Bitmap))
                       .Select(x => new { Name = x.Key.ToString(), Image = x.Value })
                       .ToList();
```

**Reflection**

Also, as another option you can use reflection on the type of your resource and find properties and shape the result this way:

```
var images = typeof(Properties.Resources)
               .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                                    BindingFlags.Public)
               .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(Bitmap))
               .Select(x => new { Name = x.Name, Image = x.GetValue(null, null) })
               .ToList();
```