# resource array or hashtable

Tags: c#, arrays, resources, hashtable

I made a chat that based from one that I found on the internet and I wanted to add emoji so I searched a set of emoji and found this: [site](http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html)
I downloaded all and added it to the resources of the project.

the images are all named in order.
now my question how can I make an array or a hash table that contains them all?

I tried doing like that:

```
Properties.Resources._+count.ToString();
```

Comment: You can find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34826151/880990

Answer (score 0):

Create a `class` with `Image` property and make collection of it to store the images.

```
    public class Emojis {

      public byte[] Image {get;set; }
    }

    var EmojiCollection = new List<Emojis> { 
        new Emojis { Image= new byte[] {}" }    // put image here
    }
```

Comment: This does neither answer the question on how to get all the images from `Properties.Resources` nor does it put them into a `Dictionary<string, Image>`, which would be appropriate (and requested by the OP). Also there is a `System.Drawing.Image` type for this. The resource manager returns them as such and there is no need to use `byte[]`.